# Is there any way to get the visual studio compiler to emit a warning for this C++ code?

Tags: c++, visual-studio

I'd really like to track down bugs of this sort, I don't really care if I get warnings if DoNothing actually does modify the value. Using VS2019, if that makes any difference.

```
void DoNothing(int&){}

int GetUninitializedInt()
{
    // uninitialized 
    int x;

    DoNothing(x);

    // still uninitialized, compiled with /Wall gives no warning
    return x;
}
```

Comment: Compilers can't catch every potential error. That's on you as a developer.

Comment: Change to `void DoNothing(const int&){}` or `void DoNothing(int){}` and it should report warning. https://godbolt.org/z/ejKoqv

Comment: Note `void DoNothing(int&)` says `DoNothing` can set value of received argument.

Answer (score 0):

Actually, the C++ compiler cannot catch such errors. You could only avoid such mistakes artificially. Therefore, I suggest that you increase the warning level to avoid this error as much as possible by setting `Properties->C/C++->General->Warning Level`.

For this question, you could modify the code:

```
void DoNothing(const int&){}

//Or

void DoNothing(int){}
```

Comment: As I say in the example code, this is already /Wall, which is the higest warning level available for the compiler. Changing the code is not an issue, it's finding the places where this error occurs.